# Maven NullPointer Exceptions

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2, soapui

I am integrating Soapui with jenkins using soapui version 5.3.0.
I am using correct plugins, and created a job on Jenkins, when running job on jenkins getting below error

```
ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to the issue tracker (https://jenkins.io/redirect/report-an-issue).
java.lang.NullPointerException
project=hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@1844c02b[Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1]
project.getModules()=[hudson.maven.MavenModule@2e2290bb[Integration-/Feature/Dev/API /Testing1/Test:gorun-Beakon][Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/Test:gorun][relativePath:], hudson.maven.MavenModule@427c50e9[Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/Test:Test][Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/Test:Test][relativePath:], hudson.maven.MavenModule@73de5944[relativePath:], hudson.maven.MavenModule@1c7bb084[Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-project][Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-project][relativePath:], hudson.maven.MavenModule@71ee9349[Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/tdrury:com.example.soapuitests][Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/tdrury:com.example.soapuitests][relativePath:]]
project.getRootModule()=hudson.maven.MavenModule@2e2290bb[Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/Test:gorun][Integration-/Feature/Dev/API/Testing1/Test:gorun][relativePath:]
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
Posting build status of FAILED to SWC Bitbucket for commit id [30fd540296aa2f090025d21cf11eef35e13e9f5d] and ref 'refs/heads/master'
Failed to post build status, additional information: timeout
Finished: FAILURE
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    
                </dependencies>    
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>gorun.xml</projectFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am tried changing my pom and other properties but not sure why i am hitting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was coming because few dependencies were missing and maven was not complaining explicitly. So when run as normal maven project, got all missing dependencies and added them resolved this issue.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).